# Are there any known ways to root the new HTC Wildfire revisions?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-wildfire, rooting, unrevoked

After using CyanogenMod on my HTC Desire for some time, i wanted to root and convert the HTC Wildfire i bought for my wife early this year.

Turns out that unrevoked is currently unable to root this particular version of the wildfire ('is your firmware too new'-error).

Are there any Known ways currently available (or available in the foreseeable future) to root said version of the wildfire?

Comment: Have you tried z4root ? Permanent root isn't available, however for some HTC devices.

Comment: Also are you running Froyo or Eclair?

Comment: froyo e.g. most current german vodafone software.

Comment: Can somebody tell me whether I'll be able to root if I do a factory reset. The phone came with Eclair. So I assume if I reset, I will be able to root? Anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

a little late for this.

Wildfire is now rootable. I did it on mine a couple of days ago. I have cyanogenmod running.

I followed the instructions in  [this site](http://joel5121.blogspot.com/2011/06/wildfire-22-root-tutorial.html)
you basically first use alpharev to unlock the S-off mode and then you install clockwork recovery to backup and then unrevocked to root.